# Is is possible to create a factory class in PHP?

Tags: php, factory-pattern

Like the BeanFactory in java:

> In the much more common case where the
>   BeanFactory itself directly creates
>   the bean by calling its constructor
>   (equivalent to Java code calling new),
>   the class attribute specifies the
>   class of the bean to be constructed.
>   In the less common case where the
>   BeanFactory calls a static, so-called
>   factory method on a class to create
>   the bean, the class attribute
>   specifies the actual class containing
>   the static factory method.

Note:it's not the factory method

```
$instance = new FactoryClass();
```

The `$instance` may be any class instance dynamically

Comment: Just FYI. I was giving you the tools to implement a factory class. Good luck.

Comment: But it's not factory class.I'm now convinced that it's impossible to create a decent factory class in PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can use __autoload combined with a static method.  This is overly simplified.

**MyObject.php:**

```
<?php
class MyObject
{
    public static function Create()
    {
        return new MyObject();
    }

    public function hello()
    {
        print('hello!!!');
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
function __autoload($className)
{
    require_once($className . '.php');
}

$o = MyObject::Create();
$o->hello();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the worlds crappiest website, but this seems to contain what you want:  http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Design-Patterns-in-PHP-Factory-Method-and-Abstract-Factory/

See the actual website for usage examples, but more or less similar to the java factory.

```
// define abstract 'ArrayFactory' class
abstract class ArrayFactory{
   abstract public function createArrayObj($type); 
}

// define concrete factory to create numerically-indexed array
objects
class NumericArrayFactory extends ArrayFactory{
   private $context='numeric';
   public function createArrayObj($type){
     $arrayObj=NULL;
     switch($type){
       case "uppercase";
         $arrayObj=new UppercasedNumericArrayObj();
         break;
       case "lowercase";
         $arrayObj=new LowercasedNumericArrayObj();
         break;
       default:
         $arrayObj=new LowercasedNumericArrayObj();
         break; 
     }
     return $arrayObj;
   }
}

// define concrete factory to create associative array objects
class AssociativeArrayFactory extends ArrayFactory{
   private $context='associative';
   public function createArrayObj($type){
     $arrayObj=NULL;
     switch($type){
       case "uppercase";
         $arrayObj=new UppercasedAssociativeArrayObj();
         break;
       case "lowercase";
         $arrayObj=new LowercasedAssociativeArrayObj();
         break;
       default:
         $arrayObj=new LowercasedAssociativeArrayObj();
         break; 
     }
     return $arrayObj;
   }
}
```

Comment: Seems too complicated,is there a simplified version?